# Выбор результатов полученных в JSON от Instagram

Tags: callback, json, php, instagram

Комрады, приветствую.

Не смог таки понять как проделать такой трюк при котором на callback.php, где получены фотографии от `Instagram` с помощью токенов, позволить пользователям выбрать нужные фотографии для дальнейшей работы с ними.

В PHP я нуб тот ещё. Нашел библиотеку готовую от Instagram тут вот: [Instagram API implementation in PHP](http://www.mauriciocuenca.com/blog/2011/02/instagram-api-implementation-in-php/) . Поставил, работает. Вот только как обработать и позволить пользователям выбирать нужные фотографии и сделать из этой каши заказ.

На готовый ответ не претендую, так как тут все довольно туманно. Кто может подскажите в какую сторону копать и искать информацию. Спасибо!

Comment: Так а что вам требуется? Загрузить картинку на свой сервер или показать юзеру?

Comment: Логин через инстаграм с записью в базу. И позволить пользователям выбрать их фотографии для печати. Отталкиваюсь от http://printstagr.am & http://stickygram.com . Надеюсь теперь понятно.

Comment: Кхм, ну в теории вам следует показать фотографии юзеру, он выберет себе нужные. Дальше вы либо загружаете себе фотографию, либо вставляете её в страницу печати через тег <img /> 
## Заголовок ##

Как напечатать страницу написано тут: http://hashcode.ru/questions/169735/javascript-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-ie